# perform segue after view controller is dimissed

Tags: swift, interface-builder, segue

I am using UINavigationController. I want to show an intermediate screen eg. White and then from there I want to dimiss and segue to green.

The reason I don't create a segue from white to green is because in the case the user goes back they should go back to blue because blue is my main screen.

[image: hurray]
Here's the code:

```
class BlueViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func tapBlue(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "whiteSegue", sender: self)
    }
}

class WhiteViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func tapGreen(_ sender: Any) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        weak var pvc = self.presentingViewController
        dismiss(animated: true){
            pvc?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "greenSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the codebase

https://github.com/omenking/DismissAndSegue

No error occurs but when white is dismissed it doesn't go to green.
I know this has been asked before on StackOverflow but the other examples did not work or were out of date with latest iOS.

Comment: Try moving logic to hide the white controller and show the green controller into the blue view controller. The tapGreen function would just call this new function. I suspect the pvc attribute is nil by the time the view controller is dismissed.

Comment: How do I move it? NotificationCenter?

Comment: Disregard comment, see answer below

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that since you are using a navigation view controller and pushing view controllers on and off the stack, the `self.presentingViewController` variable will be nil. That is used for modal presentations, not navigation view controllers.

Try this:

```
class WhiteViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func tapGreen(_ sender: Any) {
        // Get navigation stack, remove last item (White VC)
        var viewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers
        viewControllers.removeLast()

        // Instantiate new Green VC from storyboard
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) //Change bundle name
        let greenViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GreenViewController") //Change storyboard ID
        viewControllers.append(greenViewController)

        // Perform the transition to Green VC with animation
        navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different solution is to link your view controllers `blue`->`white`->`green`, and then in the green view controller, just remove the `white` view controller from the navigation stack.

Your `green` view controller then becomes as simple as this.

```
class GreenViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let count = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count {
            self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: count - 2)
        }
    }
}
```

No special handling needed in the other view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I do this, in white controller

```
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSchedule", sender: date)
     if let count = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count {
           self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: count - 2)
      }
```